# Hierarchical Multinomial Logit with no alternative-specific and different number of observations

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model, multinomial-logit

I'm working on a discrete choice problem in which several individuals of a given population undertake a number of trips during one day and, for each trip, the choice of mode is recorded (train, car, bus, etc.).

I would like to build a hierarchical model to predict the mode for each trip of each individual. Thus, the trip mode choices will be aggregated at the individual level.

In my dataset all I have is covariates at the individual level (e.g. income, education, etc.) and characteristics for each trip (e.g. duration). However I have no alternative-specific variables.

I've been trying to use the function `multinom` from the `nnet` package, but apparently only alternative specific variables can have random effects. Would anyone know how to proceed for random-effects multinomial models with only individual-specific variables?

A possible extra difficulty is that the individuals undertake a different number of trips